# What is the problem with this InOrder Traversal of Binary Tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, inorder

I implemented BinaryTree using java and tried to implement InOrder Traversal. I dry run the code on the copy in that case it works well but when I am running it on my IDE I am getting Infinite Loop. But why?
Please help.

```
 class BinaryTree{
    
    class Node{
    
            private int data;
            private Node left, right;
            public Node(int data)
            {
                this.data = data;
                left=null;
                right=null;}
}
    public void inOrderTraversal(Node root)
            {
                Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
                Node temp = root;
                stack.push(root);
                while(!stack.isEmpty())
                {
                    temp = stack.peek();
                    if(temp.left!=null)
                    {
                        stack.push(temp.left);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = stack.pop();
                        System.out.print(temp.data+" ");
                        if(temp.right!=null)
                        {
                            stack.push(temp.right);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Node one = new Node(1);
            Node two = new Node (2);
            Node three = new Node(3);
            Node four = new Node(4);
            Node five = new Node(5);
            Node six = new Node(6);
            one.left = two;
            one.right = three;
            two.left = four;
            two.right = five;
            three.left = six
    
            BinaryTrees bn = new BinaryTrees();
            bn.inOrderTraversal(one);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is `Node`? What is the value of `Node root` when your function is called?

Comment: Node here is the inner class where i defined left, right pointer for the tree and the data and root is the root of the Tree (first node).

Comment: Please provide the definition of `Node` in your question as it is highly relevant. Also, if `Node root` happens to point to itself when the function is called then it will recursively continue pushing itself onto the stack and your code will loop forever.

Comment: @h0r53 Sir StackOverflow is not allowing to post more code.It throws an error of adding some more code. Please help.

Comment: Fantastic! I'll review your code and get back to you.

Comment: Please check for one more time sir. I adjusted the code.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review my answer?

Comment: yes sir, I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code starts with `Node root` equal to `one`. To the left of `one` is `two`, and to the left of `two` is `four`. Your traversal pushes `two` then `four` to the stack before the `else` condition is taken. Then you `pop` `four`, and since `four` has nothing on the right your `while` loop starts over. But the top of the stack is now `two`. To the left of `two` is still `four`, so you push `four` on the stack and thus your infinite loop starts.

You need a way to indicate Nodes that have already been visited. If you truly must use a stack, you should add a new attribute to your Node class such as `private boolean visited` and initialize it to `false`. After each `temp = stack.pop()` you would then need to set `temp.visited = True`, and only push onto the stack Nodes that have not been visited. Such as this:

```
class Node {
    private int data;
    private Node left, right;
    private boolean visited;
    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        visited = false;
    }
}

public void inOrderTraversal(Node root) {
    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
    Node temp = root;
    stack.push(root);
    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        temp = stack.peek();
        if(temp.left != null && !temp.left.visited) {
            stack.push(temp.left);
        } 
        else {
            temp = stack.pop();
            temp.visited = true;
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
            
            if(temp.right != null && !temp.right.visited) {
                stack.push(temp.right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A much simpler solution is to use recursion:

```
public void inOrderTraveralRecursive(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    inOrderTraveralRecursive(node.left);
    System.out.print(node.data + " ");
    inOrderTraveralRecursive(node.right);
}
```

Comment: Or while pushing to the stack, check if `temp == temp.left`?

Comment: `temp == temp.left` only works if they are the same object. In the example the OP provided such a condition would not resolve the infinite loop. The appropriate solution is to use recursion.

Comment: @h0r53 Sir, the same problem is with my Post OrderTraversal too. If I mark visited each node in one traversal then in other traversals they will not be printed. Can you please give me a concrete solution. However, this solution worked if I only use InOrder in my program

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above-mentioned problems we can do the implementation using a queue and a stack here.

```
public void inOrderTraversal(Node root) {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
        Queue<Node> out = new LinkedList<>();
        Node temp = root;
        stack.push(root);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            temp = stack.peek();
            if (temp.left != null && !temp.left.visited) {
                stack.push(temp.left);
            } else {
                temp = stack.pop();
                temp.visited = true;
                out.offer(temp);

                if (temp.right != null && !temp.right.visited) {
                    stack.push(temp.right);
                }
            }
        }
        while(!out.isEmpty())
        {
            Node tempo = out.poll();
            System.out.print(tempo.data+" ");
            tempo.visited=false;
        }
    }
```

This is the proper solution.

Comment: Be careful using the word "proper" here. The most optimal solution is to use recursion. The recursive example I provided can be modified to achieve a pre, post, and in order traversal by simply moving the print statement up or down by one line.